# Drupal: find footer code

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I'm editing a Drupal that was created by a company who didn't follow Drupal best practices with the idea that only them can edit the theme. I'm having some  problems with the footer and I would like to know where is the file that contains the footer html code, because in the theme I have donwloaded (Boostrap Drupal7) it shows a footer rendered by `<?php print render($page['footer']); ?>`

The problem I have is that the footer has a block and I don't want it, but in appearance the block is not assigned to the footer, and I had tried to remove it.

Where is the code called by this function?

Answer (score 0):

First, login as admin and make sure what theme is been used, check that, here (see what is the default theme)

/admin/appearance/

Once you know what is the default theme, go to the directory and find the following template: page.tpl.php

/sites/all/themes/theme_name/templates/page.tpl.php

Find the code:

But, remember that you can find searching any string using any IDE like phpstorm or sublime. It's very simple using it.

Comment: I found `<?php print render($page['footer']); ?>` in the page.tlp.php but I don't know where is the code it renders. I don't see any file related to the footer and what happens in the current theme it happens in all themes.

Comment: Ok. So, this code:  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?> renders Items for the footer region. And you can find those items here, where you can place a block on any region: /admin/structure/block   So, check the footer region and what is there.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the footer region is empty in ** /admin/structure/block**. The problem is that the last company didn't follow good practices with the idea that only them can edit the Drupal site.

Comment: OK, so, if the footer region is empty, this peace of code does nothing. <?php print render($page['footer']); ?> . I mean, they probably just paste html code, if you delete that code (<?php print render($page['footer']); ?>) the footer still appears. So, you should find this tag '<footer' in the following templates:  /sites/all/themes/theme_name/templates/page.tpl.php or /sites/all/themes/theme_name/templates/html.tpl.php. So, my advice is, inspect the footer code with any browser and search the html code in the mentioned templates.

Comment: <?php print render($page['footer']); ?> render some HTML with what is suposed to be block (they appear in block admin page, but they are not assigned to any region)

Comment: Ok. Let'try another thing. Probably the last company place a block to  the region footer by code, so, please check if there is this code in your custom_theme: ['page']['footer'], it could be in your template.php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166815/discussion-between-daniela-and-albert).

Comment: This needs updating for Drupal 8

Comment: @WilliamK you need to find the footer in D8?

Answer (score 0):

Well, some of Brute-force approaches:

1. Do a grep of footer content in your theme folder. (sites/all/themes/xyz)

OR

2. Do a grep of footer content in your module(sites/all/modules) directory. In case, the developer has put custom module or put custom code in some module.

OR

3. Do a grep in your drupal root folder except sites folder.

OR

4. If you are able to find in which region your footer is being shown, Look in every block in that region (under admin/structure/block). Click on edit of every block in that region. See, if you are able to find the footer content.

OR

5. You can see each view (admin/structure/views)